How to search documents from different collections in mongodb using a search string
I'm currently developing an e-commerce application focused on automobile parts
I have to implement search functionality.
I am using MongoDB with mongoose in NodeJS.
It have different mongoDB collections:

Brand
CarModel
Category
Part

For example if search string is : "mahindrabrake" without even the space in the words, so it must give the brand: "Mahindra" and category: "Brake"
more examples of input search strings:



Input
Output




"mahindra xuv 500 belt"
Brand: "Mahindra", Car Model: "xuv 500", Category: "Belt"


"sonet"
Brand: "Kia", Car Model: "sonet"



I'm looking for a solution on how to parse and extract relevant information from these concatenated search strings efficiently, ensuring accurate results are returned to the user.

That is a business logic, wha't the relevance for mongo db here ?. For now you can do a full text search. For that you have to store a search key in document which may contain the expected string(s) it should match. This is not straight forward as it seems, you need to assess all the cases here. Best thing is to use delims in search string so that you can split, otherwise good luck with automata.
